# Why styles are not getting applies when edited in magento2

Tags: magento2, less

In magento2.0.2(downloaded from magentocommerce.com), after installation I created a new theme under `app/design/frontend/mypackage` with `theme.xml` , `registration.php` , `composer.json` as per the documentation.And then I inherited the `blank` theme by copying the theme files from `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank` into `mytheme` folder. Everything was fine. Now, when I add some style in `theme.less` in `web/css/source` and compile it using `grunt` , the styles are getting applied. But when I edit some of the existing styles or when I created a new less file with some styles, the styles are not getting applied.

Someone kindly explain me the reason behind this.

After doing any changes when i run `php magento setup:static-content:deploy` at front it is showing error like

[image]

Comment: do you deployed the static files????

Comment: Should I run the command ` php magento setup:static-content:deploy` after editing any style?

Comment: Yes! this will deploy all static file

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

After any css file or js file change. You need to deploy those static files to your pub static files!

So follow this steps-

1. Go to **var** folder and delete **view_preprocessed** folder
2. Also delete theme **locale** folder located in `pub/static/frontend/spacename/themename/`
3. Now from your magento root run `php bin/magento cache:flush` & `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Now your new files are ready!

Comment: can i use `grunt clean`  to delete locale file in `pub/static/frontend/spacename/themename/`

Comment: what system you are using??

Comment: do you mean what `os` am using?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You can delete without using any command

Comment: am using windows 7

Comment: You can use `grunt clean` also you can delete manually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38271/discussion-between-ramya-and-asish-hira).

Comment: I have edited my question. Kindly see that

Comment: check those file path! do you have have those files on your folder??

Comment: I have those files in `app/design/frontend/my_package/mytheme/web/css`. When I deploy it using `php magento setup:static-content:deploy` after deleting the locale folder in `pub/static/frontend` , those files are not found inside `pub/static/frontend/en_us/css`